# On RHEL8 network ports close on reboot and do not reopen without manual command

Tags: networking, rhel, networkmanager

I am on RHEL8(sophia).  My network ports do not remain UP after a repower or reboot.  I have to issue ifup eno1    and    ifup eno2    at the command line each time.    What do I need to do to have these ports initialize in the UP state upon reboot or repower?   Thank you

Answer (score 1):

In RHEL8 network is managed by NetworkManager, so you have to execute the following to  enable these interfaces during boot time :

```
nmcli device set eno1 autoconnect yes
nmcli device set eno2 autoconnect yes
```

Comment: I entered the two commands offered above. The ports remained down. re-powered computer, the ports remain down upon boot up, I still must manually enter ifup for each port in order to have network connectivity.

Comment: Please edit your question with the following commands output : `cat /etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-eno1 ; echo '-----------------------------' ; cat /etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-eno2`

Comment: Here is the result for en01. `TYPE=Ethernet
PROXY_METHOD=none
BROWSER_ONLY=no
BOOTPROTO=none
DEFROUTE=yes
IPV4_FAILURE_FATAL=no
IPV6INIT=no
IPV6_AUTOCONF=yes
IPV6_DEFROUTE=yes
IPV6_FAILURE_FATAL=no
IPV6_ADDR_GEN_MODE=stable-privacy
NAME=eno1
UUID=19e3b53d-b2d8-4378-8606-02326159ae95
DEVICE=eno1
ONBOOT=yes
IPADDR=192.168.200.72
GATEWAY=192.168.200.104
NETMASK=255.255.0.0
IPV6_PRIVACY=no
HWADDR=3C:EC:EF:1B:9A:54
PREFIX=16
PEERDNS=no
PEERROUTES=no `

Comment: All is fine in the configuration files.
It's abnormal you should check boot logs `journalctl -b 1` ; because normally both interfaces should be up during the boot time. 

Also check with the support unless you are running into a single user mode. Is it fresh Os install or an upgrade to RHEL 8 ?

Comment: Brand new computer and a fresh install.

Answer (score 0):

As a workaround I placed ifup eno1  and ifup eno2 in the /etc/rc.local file.  They are now executed on boot up.  The ports now are in an "up" state upon boot up.  I feel like this is a hack fix, but for the present it is working.